# navigating thru open modules in doors dxl

Tags: module, switch-statement, ibm-doors

When manipulating doors modules, does anyone know how to navigate through open modules. If this seems confusing I can use this example. In my script I open 2 modules.

Module apple

Module grape

I do some work in module apple, and then open module grape to do some work. What I'm looking to do is this... switch back to module apple and do some more work. I realize I could use the edit() or read() functions, but I assume this would re-open the already open module meaning my work done previously would be erased. I pretty much would try and switch between the modules where each would be in focus 1 at a time at the position I previously left off.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured it out. pretty much i did this by doing bringToFront() and then assigning this to current. Thanks for the 4 views whoever was attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also assign them to variables and switch back and forth.

```
Module A = apple
Module G = grape

for object in A do
{
  //something on the objects in A
}

for object in G do
{
  //something on the objects in G
}

for object in A do
{
  //back to A
}
```

Until you close the modules they remain open in the mode you started in. Also in response to your question about `read()` and `edit()`, those function do not open a new instance or refresh the work you have done. They will respect the current status of the module and give you a handle back to it (unless you change modes, edit to read would ask you if you want to save your changes). So either method works. Glad you figured out a solution though, good luck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To know which modules you have open up you can run this code.

```
Module m 
for m in database do 
{   
  print fullName(m) "\n" 
}
```

Now can do whatever you wish with each module handler.